# How to convert json file contains Unicode to string and save as a json file in python?

Tags: python, json, minify

I have a large JSON file. My goal is to minify in using Python.
The JSON file contains Arabic and Bengali Characters.
My problem is when I try to minify is I am getting Unicode characters instead of normal string characters like this `\u09c7`.

How can I save the minified file with normal string characters?

Below is my code:

```py
import json
filename = 'quran.json'  # file name we want to compress
newname = filename.replace('.json', '.min.json')  # Output file name
fp = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
print("Compressing file: " + filename)
print('Compressing...')

jload = json.load(fp)
newfile = json.dumps(jload, indent=None, separators=(',', ':'))
newfile = str.encode(newfile)
f = open(newname, 'wb')
f.write(newfile)
f.close()
print('Compression complete!)
```

Here is the file link in case you want to try: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nhridoy/quran-api/main/v1/quran.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it need `ensure_ascii=False` flag in `json.dumps()`

```
import json

filename = 'quran.json'  # file name we want to compress
newname = filename.replace('.json', '.min.json')  # Output file name

with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as fp:
    print("Compressing file: " + filename)
    print('Compressing...')

    jload = json.load(fp)
    newfile = json.dumps(jload, indent=None, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=False)
    #newfile = str.encode(newfile) # remove this
    with open(newname, 'w',  encoding="utf8") as f: # add encoding="utf8"
        f.write(newfile)
    
print('Compression complete!')
```